# Limit of inline nesting in c language: Is there a hard limit on this?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, inline, compiler-optimization

I am working on a project in C. When I compile, I get this error:

```
warning: inlining failed in call to 'xyz()'  --param max-inline-insns-single limit reached
```

And my compiler reports warnings as error, which I don't want to bypass.

So, is this because of too much of nesting of inline functions? Is there I can do to make it work (apart from not declaring functions inline)?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use a `#pragma` or `__attribute__`?

Comment: Note that this isn't related to nesting, it's related to the number of instructions that would be inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) point out:

> **max-inline-insns-single:**
>
> Several parameters control the tree inliner used in gcc. This number sets the maximum number of instructions (counted in GCC's internal representation) in a single function that the tree inliner will consider for inlining. This only affects functions declared inline and methods implemented in a class declaration (C++). The default value is 500.

If you still want warnings treated as errors (not an unreasonable desire), just use:

```
--param max-inline-insns-single=1000
```

(or some even greater value) to bump it up from the default.

Comment: Just curious, does C (unlike C++) require inlining when specified? In C++ it's always the compiler's prerogative.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, actually no, `inline` in C is a suggestion to the compiler: C11 6.7.4/5 "Making a function an inline function _suggests_ that calls to the function be as fast as possible".

Comment: So, the inline functions that the compiler cannot inline, will they be treated as normal non-inline functions, without reporting an error ? 
I wish I could change that parameter to 1000, I am working on a tiny module of a large project. Thanks though!

Comment: @tarun27sh, yes, if it can't be inlined, it will be a normal function, assuming you allow the compiler to compile :-) You have two options, it seems to me. Either compile as is (warnings are errors) and remove the warning by bumping up the parameter, or don't treat warnings as errors. You can localise the effects of either of those to your single module if you wish. Alternatively, if you can do neither of those, it won't be inlined anyway, so remove the `inline` keyword.

Comment: @tarun27sh `-Werror` is a double-edged sword. I would suggest mentioning the optional, "suggestion" semantics of `inline` to the project manager/administrator and getting that warning shut off. Or a review of the particular function in question.

Comment: @tarun27sh try splitting the functionality of function logically and the inline the one which is computationally intensive or both may be. As the limit is on the size of the function.

Comment: @All: Thanks for the inputs. I'll see what can be done about it. This was really informative!

Comment: That warning as an error is a very good one. If you really want the function to be inlined, e.g. because it has only one call site, then you need to make the complier do that. Surely you can override the CFLAGS for a specific module and thus can add this option to the compile command of _just_ this module.

Answer (score 0):

gcc/g++ provide options to tune the `inliner`.

```
-finline-limit=n
By default, GCC limits the size of functions that can be inlined. This flag allows the control of this limit for functions that are explicitly marked as inline (i.e., marked with the inline keyword or defined within the class definition in c++). n is the size of functions that can be inlined in number of pseudo instructions (not counting parameter handling). The default value of n is 600. Increasing this value can result in more inlined code at the cost of compilation time and memory consumption. Decreasing usually makes the compilation faster and less code will be inlined (which presumably means slower programs). This option is particularly useful for programs that use inlining heavily such as those based on recursive templates with C++.
Inlining is actually controlled by a number of parameters, which may be specified individually by using --param name=value. The -finline-limit=n option sets some of these parameters as follows:

max-inline-insns-single
is set to n/2. 
max-inline-insns-auto
is set to n/2. 
min-inline-insns
is set to 130 or n/4, whichever is smaller. 
max-inline-insns-rtl
is set to n.
```

So what you can do is increase the value of `n`. Although it is not a good idea to do in-lining  manually(compilers are pretty good at this).

Read more [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) or `man gcc`